# MUI datagrid view mode not persisting

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I'm implementing a MUI datagrid with inline editing. Whenever a cell loses focus, the code sets the mode to 'view' (as it should) but then immediately the processRowUpdate callback is called (to send data to the endpoint) it sets the cell mode back to 'edit' meaning that the cell remains in edit mode.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Maybe something to do with this processRowUpdate error logged to console?:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at getRowId (productTable.js:213:1)
    at getRowIdFromRowModel (gridRowsUtils.js:17:1)
    at useGridRows.js:106:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.updateRows (useGridRows.js:105:1)
    at apiRef.current.<computed> [as updateRows] (useGridApiMethod.js:14:1)
    at useGridCellEditing.new.js:334:1
```

Code:

```
export default function FullFeaturedCrudGrid(props) {
  const [rows, setRows] = React.useState([]);
  const [cellModesModel, setCellModesModel] = React.useState({})
  const [selectedCellParams, setSelectedCellParams] = React.useState(null);

  const { tableName } = props

  const [snackbar, setSnackbar] = React.useState(null);
  const handleCloseSnackbar = () => setSnackbar(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect called')
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/mvhr/all`)
        .then((response) => {
          setRows(response.data);
        })
  }, [])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('cellModesModel',cellModesModel)
  });

  const handleCellFocus = React.useCallback((event) => {
    const row = event.currentTarget.parentElement;
    const id = row.dataset.id;
    const field = event.currentTarget.dataset.field;
    setSelectedCellParams({ id, field });
  }, []);


  const handleDeleteClick = (id) => () => {
    axios.delete(`http://localhost:8000/delete_mvhr/${id}`
    ).then(() => {
      setRows(rows.filter((row) => row.id !== id));
      setSnackbar({ children: tableName + ' successfully deleted', severity: 'success' });  
    })
  };

  const handleCancel = () => {
    if (!selectedCellParams) {
      return;
    }
    const { id, field } = selectedCellParams;
    setCellModesModel({
      ...cellModesModel,
      [id]: {
        ...cellModesModel[id],
        [field]: { mode: GridCellModes.View },
      },
    });
  };

  const processRowUpdate = React.useCallback(
    (newRow) => {
      axios.put(`http://localhost:8000/mvhr/`, newRow)
      .then((response) => {
        const updatedRow = { ...newRow, isNew: false };
        setRows(rows.map((row) => (row.id === newRow.id ? updatedRow : row)));
        setSnackbar({ children: tableName + ' successfully saved', severity: 'success' });
        return updatedRow
      })
    });
  
  const handleProcessRowUpdateError = React.useCallback((error) => {
    setSnackbar({ children: error.message, severity: 'error' });
  }, []);  


  const columns = [
    { field: 'description', headerName: 'description', width: 180, editable: true },
    { field: 'elec_efficiency', headerName: 'elec_efficiency', type: 'number', editable: true },
    { field: 'heat_recovery_eff', headerName: 'heat_recovery_eff', type: 'number', editable: true },
    { field: 'range_low', headerName: 'range_low', type: 'number', editable: true },
    { field: 'range_high', headerName: 'range_high', type: 'number', editable: true },
    { field: 'superseded', headerName: 'superseded', type: 'boolean', editable: true },
    {
      field: 'actions',
      type: 'actions',
      headerName: 'Actions',
      width: 100,
      cellClassName: 'actions',
      getActions: ({ id }) => {
        return [
          <GridActionsCellItem
            icon={<DeleteIcon />}
            label="Delete"
            onClick={handleDeleteClick(id)}
            color="inherit"
          />,
        ];
      },
    },
  ];

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        height: '100vh',
        width: '100%',
        '& .actions': {
          color: 'text.secondary',
        },
        '& .textPrimary': {
          color: 'text.primary',
        },
      }}
    >
      <StripedDataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        processRowUpdate={processRowUpdate}
        onProcessRowUpdateError={handleProcessRowUpdateError}
        onCellEditStop={handleCancel}
        cellModesModel={cellModesModel}
        onCellModesModelChange={(model) => setCellModesModel(model)}
        components={{
          Toolbar: AddToolbar,
        }}
        componentsProps={{
          toolbar: { setRows, setSnackbar, tableName },
          cell: {
            onFocus: handleCellFocus,
          },
        }}
        experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}
        getRowClassName={(params) =>
          params.indexRelativeToCurrentPage % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'
        }
      />
      {!!snackbar && (
        <Snackbar
          open
          anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'bottom', horizontal: 'center' }}
          onClose={handleCloseSnackbar}
          autoHideDuration={6000}
        >
          <Alert {...snackbar} onClose={handleCloseSnackbar} />
        </Snackbar>
      )}
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I refactored the code to return the updatedRow synchronously rather than as a callback to the axios request:

```
  const processRowUpdate = React.useCallback(
    (newRow) => {
      const updatedRow = { ...newRow, isNew: false };
      setRows(rows.map((row) => (row.id === newRow.id ? updatedRow : row)));
      setSnackbar({ children: tableName + ' successfully saved', severity: 'success' });
      axios.put(`http://localhost:8000/mvhr/`, newRow)
      return updatedRow
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread because I didn't know the function was supposed to return the updated row. If the defined function doesn't return an updated row, then the cell will stay in edit mode from what I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Besides returning a row value, you should also wait for the async axios function in order to check if the call was succesfull.

```js
  const processRowUpdate = React.useCallback(
    async (newRow,originalRow) => {
      const updatedRow = { ...newRow, isNew: false };
      setRows(rows.map((row) => (row.id === newRow.id ? updatedRow : row)));
      setSnackbar({ children: tableName + ' successfully saved', severity: 'success' });
      try {
        const returnedRow = await axios.put(`http://localhost:8000/mvhr/`, newRow);
        return returnedRow
      }
      catch(err){
        console.log('error while saving data')//error handling logic
        return originalRow;//row before editing
      }
    });
```